# Parse not working, throwing error on complie

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a simple testing using `angularjs` `parse` method. I am not come with correct output from the testing what i do.

here is  my code for angular:

```
var parseApp = angular.module('parse',[]);
parseApp.controller('parseController', ['$scope','$parse', function($scope,$parse){
    $scope.parsedValue = "Testing";
    $scope.$watch('expr',function(newVal,oldVal,scope){
        if(newVal !== oldVal){
            var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
            $scope.parsedValue = parseFun(scope);
        }
    });
}])
```

the html is like this:

```
<div ng-app="parse">
    <div ng-controller="parseController">
        <input ng-model="expr"type="text" placeholder="Enter an expression" />
        <h2>{{ parsedValue }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

getting error as:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module parse due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'parse' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify th...<omitted>...0)
```

any one please figure-out me the wrong what i do here please?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/hXLsa/)

Comment: In JSFiddle, specify "no wrap in head" instead of "onLoad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse is a reserved word in Angular as it has a service with this name [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse), You need to have a different name, I had parse1 in your fiddler and it worked

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXLsa/3/)

Code:

```
var parseApp = angular.module('parse1',[]);
```

Comment: "no wrap in head" was not the only issue, the main problem area was the parse service keyword,